# How to filter a list by multiple parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I've got a list:

```
const list = [{
  name: 'Simon',
  age: 18
}, {
  name: 'Simon',
  age: 22
}, {
  name: 'Martha',
  age: 18
}]
```

and my filter params are:

```
const filterParams = {
  name: 'Simon',
  age: 18
}
```

I want to apply my filter params to filter my list, but I can pass one or 2 params.

```
 {
  name: 'Simon'
}

 OR

 {
  name: 'Simon',
  age: 18
}
```

My ideia is to iterate through my filterParams and filter those entries in the list.

```
const filteredList = Object.entries(filterParams).map(([key, value]) => list.filter(l => l[key] === value))
```

**USE CASES**

1. If I pass

```
{
  name: 'Simon',
  age: 18
}
```

the expected result is:

```
const expectedResult = [{
  name: 'Simon',
  age: 18
}]
```

2. If I pass

```
{
  name: 'Simon',
}
```

the expected result is:

```
const expectedResult = [{
  name: 'Simon',
  age: 18
}, {
  name: 'Simon',
  age: 22
}]
```

Somehow I couldn't figure out yet and obviously my  filter function is not working.
Here's a code snippet.

```js
const filterParams = {
  name: 'Simon',
  age: 18
}

const list = [{
  name: 'Simon',
  age: 18
}, {
  name: 'Simon',
  age: 22
}, {
  name: 'Martha',
  age: 18
}]



const filteredList = Object.entries(filterParams).map(([key, value]) => list.filter(l => l[key] === value))


const expectedResult = [{
  name: 'Simon',
  age: 18
}]

console.log('filteredList', filteredList)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `const filteredList = list.filter(l => Object.keys(filterParams).every(key => l[key] === filterParams[key]))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going thru the filters, and mapping them to each list item. What you need to do is map the list items instead, and compare each item's values to the filters.

```js
const filterParams = {
  name: 'Simon',
  age: 18
}

const list = [{
  name: 'Simon',
  age: 18
}, {
  name: 'Simon',
  age: 22
}, {
  name: 'Martha',
  age: 18
}]

const filteredList = list.filter(item => {
  return Object.keys(filterParams).every(param => {
    return filterParams[param] === item[param];
  });
});

const expectedResult = [{
  name: 'Simon',
  age: 18
}]

console.log('filteredList', filteredList)
```

Comment: `x => { return y }` can be simply `x => y`